# Reducing nested bash scripts to single file/mpirun commands

Tags: bash, shell, mpi, pbs

I regularly use something like the simplified 2 scripts below to distribute embarrassingly parallel work across a cluster with PBS/MPI. I would like to know if the commands can be merged into a single file for clarity and reduction in clutter. I am more interested in understanding the limitations of bash/mpirun than looking for alternate approaches to solving the original problem such as PBS arrays.

PBS script:

```
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=2
#PBS -q debug
#PBS -V

mpirun -n $PBS_NP $PBS_O_WORKDIR/worker_script.sh
```

worker_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
NDATA=25
DATA_ARRAY=()
for ((DATA=${OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK};DATA<${NDATA};DATA=${DATA}+${PBS_NP}))
do
    DATA_ARRAY+=(${DATA})
done
echo ${OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK} processing ${DATA_ARRAY[@]}
```

Running gives the desired output:

```
0 processing 0 4 8 12 16 20 24
1 processing 1 5 9 13 17 21
3 processing 3 7 11 15 19 23
2 processing 2 6 10 14 18 22

----------------------------------------------------------------
Jobs exit status code is 0
```

Is there any way of writing the contents of worker_script.sh inline with the mpirun command? Is there any way arounds shell expansion by the parent other than a separate file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, they led to interesting research. My personally preferred solution thus far is an extension of tripleee's bash -c tip, wrapping the worker commands in an exported function:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=2
#PBS -q debug
#PBS -V

# function
worker_function(){
NDATA=25
DATA_ARRAY=()
for ((DATA=${OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK};DATA<${NDATA};DATA=${DATA}+${PBS_NP}))
do
    DATA_ARRAY+=(${DATA})
done
echo ${OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK} processing ${DATA_ARRAY[@]}
}

# main
export -f worker_function
mpirun -n $PBS_NP bash -c 'worker_function'
```

This follows typical program structure and works with vim's syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
stuff
here
```

(save for scripts with here documents) can equivalently be expressed on a single logical line as

```
bash -c 'stuff; here'
```

or even somewhat more readably

```
bash -c 'stuff
    here'
```

(in which case you can even embed a here document.)

If your script contains single quotes, that will obviously have to be worked around somehow.

Having the script inside single quotes protects it from wildcard expansion, variable substitution, etc.

Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

Well No... not usually. `man mpirun` "mpirun"  is a shell script that attempts to hide the differences in starting jobs for various devices from the user. Typical usage:

```
mpirun -np <number of processes> <program name and arguments>
```

mpirun takes a program name (or in your case the script name $PBS_O_WORKDIR/worker_script.sh) as an argument, so in general it expects to call a different file. However, there are a number of machine specific options to `mpirun` regarding batch mode operation, that, in bash, may allow the use of a heredoc within the PBS script to feed `mpirun` the required information.